# C# - How to extend UserLoginEventSuccessEvent

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization

I would like to extend the `UserLoginSuccessEvent` to include a second `IPrincipal` object like so:

```
public class MyCompanyUserLoginSuccessEvent : UserLoginSuccessEvent
{
    public IPrincipal MyCompanyUser { get; }

    public TylerUserLoginSuccessEvent(string username, string subjectId, string name, IPrincipal myCompanyUser)
        : base(username, subjectId, name)
    {
        MyCompanyUser = myCompanyUser;
    }
}
```

Then it is called like this:

```
            var myCompanyAuthenticationResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            await _events.RaiseAsync(new MyCompanyUserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id, user.UserName, myCompanyAuthenticationResult.Principal));

            authenticationResult.Properties.Items.TryGetValue("returnUrl", out string returnUrl);
            
            return await RedirectToReturnUrl(returnUrl);
```

However, I have been unsuccessful at trying to access `MyCompanyUser` from the code that calls this API.

Basically, I just need the BaseController in C# MVC to be able to have multiple `User` properties so I can see both who they're logged in as on the website and from the company perspective.

Somehow, the basic `Controller` object in C# MVC is setting this `User` property and I don't understand how I add another user to it.

Comment: Before I get into it, are you trying to see all users logged in?

Because there is only one user in that context of that request. At least when focused on a single request and you are currently debugging. For security, you shouldn't be able to identify other users request data unless its been coded that way, which I wouldn't recommend.

Suffice to say, HttpContext.User should be what I think you are looking for and should be available to you. I apologize if I misunderstood the question.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @HouseCat No, we have two separate authentications - one for the website, and one for active directory. When they login with the website user, they also have to login via active directory. I would like to know both the accounts they logged in as